# The splash screen is distorted for windows surface 3 tablet

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

The issue is that the splash screen is distorted for windows surface 3 tablet but is coming in correct aspect ratio for windows 10 desktops and windows 10 laptops. Is there a specific screen resolution which we have to take care of to cover windows surface 3 too.

The windows app is a cordova based application developed in visual studio 2015.

Comment: use tableview.reloadSection()

Comment: that is for reloading the section..how to move that row from one section to other inside  button linked function @ĐinhQuangHiếu

Comment: Add that object to second array and remove from first array, then call reloadSection

Comment: @ĐinhQuangHiếu can you give me the code for it

Comment: @Rouny show youyr code and arrays.